# How can i ssh from one ubuntu machine to another with a cable (no router) and communicate over ipv6, without configuring anything?

Tags: ssh, ethernet, ipv6

What are the minimal steps necessary to do ssh and rsync over ipv6 between two ubuntu machines connected only by an rj45 (cat 5 or cat6) ethernet cable?  (So no router nor even a switch is involved, just a cable and a couple of hosts with multiple ethernet ports via ethernet-over-usb.)

I want to use ipv6 because i understand every ethernet device as an ipv6 address associated with it.

So i don't want to assign any addresses, just use the `fe80::*********` that the interfaces come with.  I also don't want to use DHCP or any other service where i have to make any decisions or do anything.

What i've tried doing is using `sudo ip link set enx******* up` for the interface on one machine (ethernet-over-usb).  Sometimes this works enough that i can ping one machine from the other, but sometimes setting the link to up has no effect (i.e., makes no difference to the results of calling `ip addr show dev enx*******`).  When the ping works, the command is `ping enx****** fe80::****:****:****:****`, with the `*` replaced with the actual device name and ipv6 address in all cases.  (And although sometimes ping works, ssh never does.  And i figured out the ipv6 address to ping using wireshark.)

I'm running xubuntu 22.04 on one machine and xubuntu 20.04 on the other.

Seems like this should be easy and nearly automatic since the ipv6 addresses are already assigned.